# Is Classic ASP Session.Variables costly?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, session-variables, iis-8

I have read a lot of articles about session variables in Classic Asp.

I already know that **accessing Request.Servervariables is costly**, as the entire collection have to be fetched by the Asp Script from IIS, everytime a particular item is requested.

I was dumbly wondering if the same apply for session variables... ?
Would it be a good idea to collect the few session.variables I am using when the script start, one time for all ?

The following article suggest (as I believed too) that Session.Contents does not suffer the same inefficiency as Request.ServerVariables? as the Sesison is made available one-time-for-all by IIS : Is that true ?
https://web.archive.org/web/20210927201638/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092298-3.shtml

*NOTE : My use of session variables is very very sparse, but I am looking for every bit of optimization :)*

Comment: You only use `Request.ServerVariables` on the server, not sure what you mean by "fetched from the server"? Regardless I've never had a performance issue with either `Request.ServerVariables` or `Session` variables in fact as `Session` variables are short lived unless you are trying to store complex object you should never have a performance issue. But this is all opinion which makes this question a poor fit for [so].

Comment: This is a hard question for which to provide a useful answer. It depends on usage. Session in classic ASP is managed by IIS on the server. As a metaphor, think of it as a csv file private to each user. If you have millions of users but very little session data then the burden has one profile, if you have ten users with a million large session variables it has another. Session data will be managed via IIS like any other server memory resource, so is susceptible to swaps, disk waits, etc. My advice is to set out to use IIS session then develop another strategy if you find a performance issue.

Comment: And just to add, if you are intending to scale to use simple load balancing or a server farm then use of IIS session is problematic. You can research that and solutions elsewhere on the web. Not a great question for SO.

Comment: Ok, I have very very well understood that you judge my question Not Advisable for StackOverflow. I always appreciate when someone judge the question instead of simply providing what is initially desired : an anwser. So thank your for the general knowledge about ASP Sessions — I already knew it (but you were not supposed to be informed that it was the case) — and I wiil in the future avoid asking precise questions illustrated by external links, built with a non-evasive formulation. Instead, I will try to do the exact opposite SO's guidelines are recommending. We'll see what it will lead to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**That's obsolutely true.**

Short answer is, if you need session variable (or application, this is the same) once, you can use it directly :

```
<%=session("userLastName")%>, <%=session("userFirstName")%>
```

If you need session variable many times, do a copy locally (this is a array in this example) :

```
<%
localAryCopy = session("myArray")
for each tmp in localAryCopy
    response.write tmp
next
%>
```

Last week, someone ask me to check why his asp classic application a a TTFB (time to first byte) to 3 second.  He was using 3 sessions variables many times (3 for each embeded, for a total of about 100 loop).  I just made local copy, and TTFB drop to about 50ms.

Comment: Huge improvement ! I will perform some tests to ensure wich solution is better for me, but thank your for your example that is a clear proof, and your concise anwser that will lead me to dig deeper this "Session thing" :-)